# Access a running Clojure system via remote REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have a web server running in a JVM which uses Clojure. I want to remote connect to this JVM from a REPL, but I cannot find any "CLEAR" steps which work on how I can do this. Has anyone already done this?

Note: I can use either the standard REPL or jline

Comment: Why do you put irony quotes around "clear"?

Comment: I put quotes around "clear" because I am not a very technical person, and often I need more simplified answers than the average StackOverflow user

Answer (score 4):

You can include [nREPL](https://github.com/cemerick/nREPL) in your code. If you just want to look into JVM heap and other statistics you can use [jconsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using GNU screen http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/? It lets you connect to anything running in terminal.

EDIT: [Here](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/introduction-to-gnu-screen/) is a good short intro to Screen with more advanced links in the end. It is actually very simple to use and extremely useful if you work on remote machines, so I recommend looking into it.

Comment: I looked at GNU Screen but it was too complex for me to understand.

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial that will get you started easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Emacs, http://asymmetrical-view.com/2009/08/20/emacs-slime-remote-repl.html describes how you would connect your local Emacs to a remote swank-clojure.